# Webpack Hot Module Replacement for KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, webpack, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

I'm trying to get HMR to work for my knockout application and currently struggling to get HMR to reload whenever I change something inside the `viewModel` itself, but anything outside the scope will work.

Example:

```
//hmr.js

require('mymodule');

if(module.hot)
  module.hot.accept();
```

---

```
// mymodule.js
function myViewModel(params) {
  console.log('this will only be logged once'); // This one doesn't change after saving
}

console.log('I can get this to be logged multiple times without reload');

module.exports = {
  viewModel: myViewModel,
  template: '<div>just some stuff here</div>'
};
```

I'm wondering if I need to do something else to tell HMR to retrigger things inside the `viewModel`? currently in my `main.js` file I have `ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());` which only being fired once and I have `ko.components.register()` inside my `main.js` file as well which require in my `mymodule` file.